# How to Efficiently Pass XML Documents between Camel routes through ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a series of Camel routes that retrieve, transform, split, and combine XML documents. This all works fine.

These routes are linked by ActiveMQ topics and queues.

All good.

However, in some cases I have a large number of documents to process, and because Camel's JMS component transforms XML documents into text for the message, the queues result in the rendering of the XML to string, and re-parsing to documents more than once, which is a significant processing overhead.

I've tried setting the JMS producer `jmsMessageType` to `Object`, but when the consumer retrieves the message, and I output `exchange.getIn().getBody().getClass().getCanonicalName()` I get `java.lang.String`.

What settings would I need to put on the producer and the consumer for the XML Document objects to be passed directly through the ActiveMQ topic/queue without being rendered to String and re-parsed?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

Xerces [supports Java serialization](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html#faq-4) of its DOMs and Camel [supports Java serialization](https://camel.apache.org/serialization.html). It's questionable though if it's really more efficient, quoting from Xerces documentation:

> Some rough measurements have shown that XML serialization performs better than Java object serialization and that XML instance documents require less storage space than object serialized DOMs.

And there's another catch: Camel's Java serialization data format is deprecated and there's a risk that it will be removed in an upcoming Camel version. The implementation is very straight forward though and in case it gets deprecated you could add a custom data format replicating current Camel [SerializationDataFormat](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/SerializationDataFormat.java).

If you want to try it out though, the producer could look like:

```
from(...)
    // you need to hava Xerces DOM object in the exchange body at this point
    .marshal().serialization()
    .to("jms:myqueue");
```

...and consumer:

```
from("jms:myqueue")
  .unmarshal().serialization()
  // you should have your Xerces DOM again
  ...
```